# Unbiased estimator sample mean

Tags: statistics

If $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample on a probability space $(\Omega, p)$, show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is an unbiased estimator for $E(X_1)$.

It seems an obvious computation, \begin{align*}
E(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot n E(X_1)=E(X_1)
\end{align*}
Since the random variables are identically distributed. However, if I'm carefully using the definition of unbiased estimator, it becomes more difficult for me to see.

In this case, we would technically say, If there is

1. a parameter $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ to be estimated
2. a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$
3. a parameterization of probability measures $\mu_{\theta}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

then the $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is an unbiased estimator if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(\omega)\mu_{\theta}(d\omega)=\theta$.

Here $g(\omega)=g(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$.If we fix $\theta=E(X_1)$, then this amounts to fixing a probability measure $\mu_{\theta}$. But how does that actually help you integrate g, when you don't know what this measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is? Moreover, the integral for $g$ itself seems to have nothing to do with the random sample $X_1,...,X_n$, which doesn't seem correct. Is the dependence on $X_1,...,X_n$ encoded in the probability measure $\mu_{\theta}$?

Comment: You're integrating over all possible values of $X_1,\ldots, X_n$, that is, the domain of $g$

Comment: @Julio Puerta so you mean, you're really integrating $g$ against over $Range(X_1,...,X_n)$, as opposed to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Even so, you can have different random vectors $(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ that assume the same range values. It seems to be this definition should be taking into account how these values are distributed.

Comment: Yes, at least that is the definition I'm used to work with; that way you don't have to force $g$ to be defined in all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I assume both definitions are equivalent, but maybe someone that is more familiar with the one you propose may enlighten us